# Can't login into Ubuntu 13.10, can't Ctrl Alt F1

Tags: 13.10, login

As the title sugests, I'm stuck at the login screen of my Ubuntu 13.10. I enter my password correctly, press enter and the screen goes black for a second then the login screen shows again. Tried several solutions already. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (any F, in fact) the screen goes black and then loading screen again.

I'm REALLY desperate for a solution...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer to this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: Try reinstalling the complete OS. But doing so, it will permanently erase your personal files in the current Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting to gdm. Can you select single user mode (command prompt only mode) on the boot menu? If so, try to log in from there. Once you get logged in to a command prompt, create a new user with the command sudo adduser NEWNAME (NEWNAME is whatever you want). This will create a new /home/user directory for that user. Then reboot and try to log in as that user. It will probably work, which means some setting in your old /home were corrupted. The easiest thing to do then is just to copy your old /home/user data to your new /home/user folder.

Ok it sounds like you may have deleted a system partition. What I would do is make a live cd or better still thumb drive you can keep with you, then boot into that and mount your file system. Back up your /home partition (if it's there, it sounds like it may not be) and reload.

Comment: Didn't work. Exactly the same thing happened with the new account. This also happens with the guest account. I must say that I couldn't boot in prompt only mode. As ctrl alt F1 doest work either, the only way I could access the prompt was pressing M at the purple UBUNTU screen to "enter manual recovery mode" (the system tries to scan an partition I deleted yesterday, so this appears).

Comment: Correction: I dont know how to access single user mode, so I simply pressed M as I explained :/

Answer (score 0):

have you try to access to another tty by using Ctrl+Alt+F2 by example?
If you can do it, type this command : sudo rm .Xauthority, then return to login screen (Ctrl+Alt+F7) and try again.